# How many electrons does the b6-f complex need to pump one proton into the thylakoid lumen?

Tags: photosynthesis

In photosynthesis, photons are used through photolysis to split water molecules and retrieve their hydrogen ions and electrons in the water-splitting complex. For each four photons, two water molecules are split and four electrons are retrieved.

The electrons will go on to pass into chlorophyll *a* in photosystem II and after being excited by another photon, pass through a series of electron carriers and drop energy along the way. One of these electron carriers is the cytochrome b6-f complex which uses some of this energy to help pump hydrogen ions from the chloroplasts stroma and into the thylakoids lumen.

However, I'm unsure of exactly how many electrons the b6-f complex needs to pump each hydrogen ion across the membrane. Is it 2? 4? I've been unable to find an answer anywhere so far.